# Missing S3 Connection in Local Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, airflow

I have an Airflow task where I try to load a text file into an S3 bucket. I have Airflow set up locally and have done

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[amazon]'
```

I then run `airflow standalone`.

To set up the connection with AWS S3, I go to the Airflow UI and go to "Admin" --> "Connections".

The issue is that when I try to run via the Airflow UI, I get the following error

```
[2022-10-24, 01:21:36 UTC] {base_aws.py:117} INFO - No connection ID provided. Fallback on boto3 credential strategy (region_name=None). See: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html
```

However, when I test the dag locally via:

```
airflow dags test dag_name
```

and I have my AWS credentials locally in `~/.aws/credentials` it does work. Am I setting the connection wrong in the airflow UI?

For what it's worth if it's relevant here's my python file where I set up the dag

```
#datetime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

# The DAG object
from airflow import DAG

# Operators
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook

import boto3

# initializing the default arguments
default_args = {
        'owner': 'Owner',
        'start_date': datetime(2022, 10, 21),
        'retries': 3,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

# Instantiate a DAG object
write_data_to_s3_test_dag = DAG('write_data_to_s3_test_dag',
        default_args=default_args,
        description='Write Data to S3 Test DAG',
        schedule=None, 
        catchup=False,
        tags=['example, writedatatos3']
)


def upload_to_s3(filename: str, key: str, bucket_name: str) -> None:
    hook = S3Hook('s3_conn')
    hook.load_file(filename=filename, key=key, bucket_name=bucket_name)

# Creating first task
start_task = EmptyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=write_data_to_s3_test_dag)

write_data_to_s3_test_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='write_data_to_s3_test_task',
    python_callable=upload_to_s3,
    op_kwargs={
        'filename': '/path/to/test.txt',
        'key': 'test.txt',
        'bucket_name': 'test-bucket'
    },
    dag=write_data_to_s3_test_dag
)

# Creating third task
end_task = EmptyOperator(task_id='end_task', dag=write_data_to_s3_test_dag)

# Set the order of execution of tasks. 
start_task >> write_data_to_s3_test_task >> end_task
```

Comment: if you run in the terminal "airflow connections list" do you see your connection ?